Getting Validation failed error when using '.' and '+' both in the email field
customer-schema.ts:
 import joi from 'joi';
 import { email } from './common-schema';

    const firstName = joi.string().required().messages({
        'string.empty': 'First name is required',
    });
    const lastName = joi.string().required().messages({
        'string.empty': 'Last name is required',
    });
    const role = joi.string().required().messages({
        'string.empty': 'Role is required',
    });
    const shortName = joi.string().required().messages({
        'string.empty': 'NRPCD Register Number is required',
    });
    const smsNumber = joi
        .string()
        .allow('')
        .pattern(/^(((\+44)|(0)|(44)) ?\d{4} ?\d{6}|\d{4} ?\d{6})$/)
        .messages({
            'string.max': 'SMS number is invalid',
            'string.pattern.base': 'SMS number is invalid',
        });
    export const createDefaultUserSchema = joi.object({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        role,
        sms_number: smsNumber,
    });
    export const createCustomerSchema = joi.object({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        role,
        sms_number: smsNumber,
    });
    export const createInterpreterSchema = joi.object({
        firstName,
        lastName,
        email,
        role,
        shortName,
        sms_number: smsNumber,
    });
    common-schema.ts
    import joi from 'joi';
    // eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
    export const email = joi
        .string()
        //.email({ tlds: { allow: false } })
        .pattern(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/)
        .required()
        .messages({
            'string.empty': 'Email is required',
            'string.email': 'Email is invalid',
        });
    export const password = joi.string().required().messages({
        'string.empty': 'Password is required',
    });

I am using the regex pattern that supports both . and + together in email but still when I am using this both at the same time like Pooja.thakur+Pooja2@gmail.com then it is giving me validation failed error on the other hand In case of Poojathakur+Pooja2@gmail.com is it is working fine. I want if I type something like this in email field Pooja.thakur+Pooja2@gmail.com, it should work. Any help is appreciated

I think you need to trace into joi and figure out what it is doing. Pasting this into the browser console shows the RegExp is fine: RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/).exec("Pooja.thakur+Pooja2@gmail.com")

Actually, the regex you are using is working. I don't think there is a mistake in the regular expression because it is clear that "[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+" can accept any number of dots, percents, underscores, hyphens, or a combination of these.
See a demonstration here:


then what can be the other reason that is causing this validation error if this regex pattern is correct...any idea?
